# Altering view/access permissions for a schema in DB2

Tags: db2, sql-grant, database-permissions

I am working around a workaround to a "feature" in IBM DB2.

This fancy database has a "feature" in it which if I try to use a `CREATE TABLE` statement and it doesn't find the schema, it will create this schema for me, even if I don't want it to. This bug has caused me a lot of hours in debugging, because my code right now exists with the expectation that it *won't* create the schema if it doesn't exist

My question is -- how do I change the permissions of a particular schema (or even during the create schema phase) which a particular user does not have access to view?

I checked out this [doc](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000964.html)..

It seems with `GRANT`, there are the following three permissions:

> ALTERIN 
>   Grants the privilege to alter or comment on all objects in the
>   schema. The owner of an explicitly created schema automatically
>   receives ALTERIN privilege.
>
> CREATEIN 
>   Grants the privilege to create
>   objects in the schema. Other authorities or privileges required to
>   create the object (such as CREATETAB) are still required. The owner of
>   an explicitly created schema automatically receives CREATEIN
>   privilege. An implicitly created schema has CREATEIN privilege
>   automatically granted to PUBLIC.
>
> DROPIN 
>   Grants the privilege to drop
>   all objects in the schema. The owner of an explicitly created schema
>   automatically receives DROPIN privilege

With only ALTERIN, CREATEIN, and DROPIN, I don't see anything relevant to view access permissions :/

EDIT:

I checked out our Dash DB database for this particular table which has these special permissions for particular users using the following SQL:

`SELECT * FROM SYSIBMADM.PRIVILEGES WHERE OBJECTSCHEMA = 'FAKE_SCRATCH';`

This is the result:

[image]

EDIT 2:

I tried the following to emulate Dash DB's permissions for that user for that schema:

`GRANT ALTERIN, CREATEIN, DROPIN ON SCHEMA FAKE_SCRATCH TO USER TEST_USER;`

[image]

Still doesn't work :/

Comment: It's all a matter of setting up permissions properly for your database -- [IMPLICIT_SCHEMA](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.sec.doc/doc/c0005525.html) -- but then you'd complain it's too restrictive.

Comment: @mustaccio thanks for this link! So I guess these `RESTRICTIVE` permissions can only be done in schema creation phase?

Comment: No, you can only specify `RESTRICTIVE` when you create a database. In an existing database you should revoke `IMPLICIT_SCHEMA` from `PUBLIC` (and don't let your applications connect as a user with the DBADM privilege).

Comment: @mustaccio thanks again for the help. I checked the article you shared and even the accompanied link, but I couldn't really see where it shows us how to revoke `IMPLICIT_SCHEMA` from `PUBLIC`? Also, how would I not let the application connect as a user with the DBADM privilege? If you can write this as an answer, I would immediately mark you as answer!

Comment: You revoke a privilege with a `REVOKE` statement, and you don't allow applications to connect by not giving away the password for authorization IDs that you want to protect.

Comment: @mustaccio Just wanted to clarify -- we should revoke `IMPLICIT_SCHEMA` on non-admin users right? I tried revoking it for both a regular user and admin user (`REVOKE PUBLIC`), and the admin user would still be able to create schemas implicitly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following SQL query executed in DB2 fixed the problem:

```
REVOKE IMPLICIT_SCHEMA ON DATABASE FROM PUBLIC
```